# Elegant and efficient way to start GUI programs from terminal without spamming it (Bash or any Posix shell)

Tags: bash, shell, user-interface, posix, stdout

Every once in a while I have to fire up a GUI program from my terminal session to do something. It usually is Chrome to display some HTML file are some task alike.
These programs however throw warnings all over the place and it can actually become ridiculous to write anything so I always wanted to redirect `stderr`/`stdout` to `/dev/null`.

While `($PROGRAM &) &>/dev/null` seems okay I decided to create a simple Bash function for it so I don't have to repeat myself everytime.

So for now my solution is something like this:

```
#
# silly little function
#
gui ()
{
  if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    ($@ &) &>/dev/null
  else
    echo "missing argument"
  fi
}

#
# silly little example
#
alias google-chrome='gui google-chrome'
```

So what I'm wondering about is:

- Is there a way without an endless list of aliases that's still snappy?
- Are there different strategies to accomplish this?
- Do other shells offer different solutions?

In asking these questions I want to point out that your strategies and solutions might deviate substantially form mine. Redirecting output to /dev/null and aliasing it was the only way I know but there might be entirely different ways that are more efficient.

Hence this question :-)

Comment: good start. re. endless list of aliases. the only solution I see are "name-shortners", maybe alias gc='gui google-chrome', but you still need a bunch of aliases. Else you can just use your function with hardlink to shortened names to programs. ie `ln gc google-chrome`. then `gui gc`. Of course you have to watch for name collisions with existing programs. You could also look into features of program-name completion in bash/zsh (maybe), but you can spend a lot of time setting that stuff up AND Debugging VS straightforward 1 time commitment for aliases. OR fn loop to build list of aliases.GdLuk.

Comment: Thanks man.
The google-chrome alias was obviously just an example ;-)
I just wanted to create an example people would understand.

Comment: And I agree: aliases seems to be a more transparent way of doing things than setting up my own completion script since everyone is already used looking for aliases in a new environment.

Comment: Did you check the command `setsid`? It may have saved you from writing the function you have written.

Comment: @anishsane I didn't know it but I just tried. However `setsid google-chrome www.google.com"` will still output something to my terminal ("Created new window in existing browser session." to be precise)

Comment: I'm probably preaching to the choir here, but properly written GUI applications run quietly unless there is a serious error, or you enable verbose diagnostics.

Comment: ^^ Not really, many apps DO have debug information by default... because it is generally assumed that they will not be started via terminal.

Comment: You can wrap bash to make it run every command with this `gui` function, but you still need to tell gui-less apps appart. The only wacky thing I come with is using `ldd` or something like that to see if it uses graphical toolkits. Your real problem is you don't have a way to tell which applications have a GUI.

Comment: I was doing some research in the Stack Overflow meta and was getting the idea that cross-posting or multi-posting was an okay thing to do as long as the question fits and is adding value to the network.
And I agree managed cross-posts would be more desirable!

Comment: How about using GNU Screen to use a "spare" screen for launching X stuff. That way the spare screen gets littered on and not your main terminal.

Comment: I set up my window manager (menu) to launch my most frequently used GUI applications, not a terminal.  Is there any reason you prefer typing `google-chrome` to using a button or menu to launch it?

Comment: @Tim `screen` is another nice approach.

Personally I am not even remotely interested in what these applications usually spam ;-)
But yes, `screen` was one of my earlier approaches, too.

Comment: @jw013 try this with your mouse:
`google-chrome \`curl -s --get --data-urlencode "q=example" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0 | sed 's/"unescapedUrl":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/;s/.*GwebSearch",//'\``

More serious answer:
When I'm doing this I'm trying to avoid using the mouse because it's not in my hand. Also often enough I actually pipe stuff to Chrome for example.

Comment: @EnnoWeichert That looks like a fairly specific usage, in which case, your solution seems fine.  There is no "endless list of aliases", just one.  How many GUI applications besides Chrome do you feel the need to run from the terminal?  Probably not an endless number.  (Also, I never said anything about a mouse - it takes me about 3 keystrokes to launch firefox from my window manager, no mouse required.)

Comment: @jw013 I agree the pipe is very specific. Starting GUI programs from shell however is not and I see myself starting a number of those. Often I make use of the fact that by opening a file a an already open GUI program, the file is opened in that instance, in a tab (goes for editors, media-players etc). So from my standpoint it's pretty useful to be able to start a GUI program and silence it. But yes aliases are a pretty reliable and transparent way of doing it and I'm not particularly dissatisfied, I just know there's always a better solution ;-)

Comment: @EnnoWeichert Start the GUI app from the window manager so its output doesn't go to a terminal, and then you can open tabs / files or connect to it using terminal commands without getting "output pollution".  This is how Debian sets up iceweasel.

Comment: @jw013 it is a viable strategy, I give you that.
Personally I don't see the benefit in starting my programs from the window manager though (even if it was ratpoinson for that matter). As to "output pollution": I don't know how successful this approach would be, but I might try this approach if only for reference.

Comment: @EnnoWeichert For me, benefits of using the window manager are fewer keystrokes (for iceweasel, 3 vs typing `icew<Tab><Enter>`), WM shortcuts are globally accessible (no need to switch to a not-busy terminal), and lack of output pollution (output goes to `~/.xsession-errors` instead).

Comment: I see what you mean. Flagged for attention to have it merged with the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed in the comments, I think the real problem is a way to distinguish between gui vs. non-gui apps on the commandline. As such, the cleanest way I could think of is to put this part of your script:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    ($@ &) &>/dev/null
  else
    echo "missing argument"
  fi
```

into a file called `gui`, then `chmod +x` it and put it in your `~/bin/` (make sure `~/bin` is in your `$PATH`). Now you can launch gui apps with:

```
`gui google-chrome`
```

on the prompt.

**Alternatively**, you can do the above, then make use of `bind`:

```
bind 'RETURN: "\e[1~gui \e[4~\n"'
```

This will allow you to just do:

```
google-chrome
```

on the prompt and it would automatically append `gui` before `google-chrome`

Or, you can bind the above action to `F12` instead of `RETURN` with

```
bind '"\e[24~": "\e[1~gui \e[4~\n"'
```

To separate what you want launched with `gui` vs. non-gui.

More discussion on binding [here](https://superuser.com/questions/117227/a-command-before-every-bash-command) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/167283/is-there-a-way-to-preprocess-input-to-bash).

These alternatives offer you a way out of endless aliases; a mix of:

- Putting `gui` in your `~/bin/`, and
- Binding use of `gui` to `F12` as shown above

seems the most ideal (albeit hacky) solution.

---

**Update - @Enno Weichert's Resultant Solution:**

Rounding this solution out ...

This would take care of aliases (in a somewhat whacky way though) and different escape encodings (in a more pragmatic rather than exhaustive way).

Put this in `$(HOME)/bin/quiet`

```
#!/bin/bash -i

if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
  # Expand if $1 is an alias
  if [ $(alias -p | awk -F "[ =]" '{print $2}' | grep -x $1) > 0 ] ; then
    set -- $(alias $1 | awk -F "['']" '{print $2}') "${@:2}"
  fi
  ($@ &) &>/dev/null
else
  echo "missing argument"
fi
```

And this in `$(HOME)/.inputrc`

```
#
# Bind prepend `quiet ` to [ALT][RETURN]
#
# The condition is of limited use actually but serves to seperate
# TTY instances from Gnome Terminal instances for me.
# There might very well be other VT emulators that ID as `xterm`
# but use totally different escape codes!
#
$if $term=xterm
  "\e\C-j": "\eOHquiet \eOF\n"
$else
  "\e\C-m": "\e[1~quiet \e[4~\n"
$endif
```

Comment: Giving this one some thought and testing, the main problem I have with it (as with my original attempt) is that you cannot use it with aliases. But it's definitely my favorite so far.

Comment: can't believe that edit was rejected several times ... but hey thanks man :-D

Comment: @EnnoWeichert np =) I thought it was useful + relevant to be put in the same place

Comment: small syntax error: in the .inputrc part it is `term=xterm` instead of `$term=...` also one might want to have `$input /etc/inputrc` in that file ... learning as we do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an ugly hack, I sometimes use [`nohup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/nohup.1.html) for a similar needs. It has the side effect of redirecting the command's output, and it makes the program independent of the terminal session.

For the case of running GUI programs in a desktop envinroment it has only little risk for resource leaks as the program will anyway end with window manager session. Nevertheless it should be taken into account.

There is also the option of opening another terminal session. In Gnome for instance, you can use `gnome-terminal --comand 'yourapp'`.
But this will result in opening many useless terminal windows.

Comment: Doesn't `nohup` mean it doesn't regard hangups anymore? So that when you log out this process will not get shut down gracefully?
Somehow that seems to be a bad idea (especially) for resource-intensive applications like Chrome ...

Comment: Yes, it is a risk, I should be downvoted for being hasty and reckless with this. I will edit.

Comment: Alright, still there is the issue of `nohup` creating a log-file by default and of course this is only taking care of the `gui` function in my example you would still have to create all the aliases necessary.

I disregard the gnome-terminal idea since it wouldn't help with any of the tasks (detaching, silencing, automating). Simple test for this: start `gnome-terminal --command gedit` like this, go to the just created gnome-terminal and go to the options dialog. There is usually some Gtk warning at this point - in your original shell.

Comment: You are correct, my use of `nohup` isn't intended for solving the aliases problem, but it is a solution for starting another application without interrupting the main terminal window. And with less dependency. Alike, the `gnome-terminal` will take the mess off the terminal window that it is launched from to another side window. I couldn't reproduce any output to the original terminal with the command in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a great idea to launch GUI applications from the terminal, as this reduces mouse usage. It's faster, and more convenient in terms of options and arguments. For example, take the browser. Say you have the URL in the clipboard, ready to paste. Just type, say, `ice` (for Iceweasel) and hit Shift-Insert (to paste) and Enter. Compare this to clicking an icon (possibly in a menu), wait for the window to load (even worse if there is a start up page), then click the URL bar (or hit Ctrl-L), then Ctrl-V... So I understand you desire for this to work.

But, I don't see how this would require an "infinite" list of aliases and functions. Are you really using that many GUI applications? And even so, aliases are one line - functions, which may be more practical for handling arguments, are perhaps 1-5 lines of (sparse) code. And, don't feel you need to set them up once and for all - set them up one by one as you go along, when the need arises. Before long, you'll have them all.

Also, if you have a tabbed terminal, like urxvt (there is a Perl extension), you'd benefit from moving from "GUI:s" to "CLI:s": for downloading, there's rtorrent; for IRC, irssi; instead of XEmacs (or `emacs`), `emacs -nw`; there is a CLI interface to vlc for streaming music; for mail, Emacs' rmail; etc. etc.! Go hunt :)

(The only sad exception I've run across that I think is a lost cause is the browser. Lynx, W3M, etc., may be great from a technical perspective, but that won't always even matter, as modern web pages are simply not designed with those, text-only browsers in mind. In all honesty, a lot of those pages look **a lot** less clear in those browsers.)

Hint: To get the most out of a tabbed terminal, you'd like the "change tab" shortcuts "close" (e.g., Alt-J for previous tab and Alt-K for next tab, not the arrow keys that'll make you reach).

Last, one solution that'll circumvent this problem, and that is to launch the "GUI:s" as background processes (with `&`) in your `~/.xinitrc` (including your terminal emulator). Not very flexible, but great for the stuff you always use, every time you use your computer.

Comment: regarding TUI programs vs GUI programs: the nature of this question kind of implies that I already do that but there's simply no good alternative for a browser like Chrome or Firefox. And I wouldn't even search for one as I'm comfortable with using GUI programs - just not with them spamming random debugging BS. Regarding the strategy of starting programs beforehand (via .xinitrc for example): I do that as well with Chrome and Terminator. There was also the idea to manipulate these windows (adding tabs etc.) from the command-line somewhere in the comments.

Comment: @EnnoWeichert: Right, we are stuck with those browsers, it seems. Debugging BS, haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I kept thinking that the one function should be enough. No aliases, no bashisms, no nonsense. But it seemed to me that the only the way to do that without possibly affecting regular use, such as expansions and completions, was to put the function at the end of the command. This is not as easy as one might first assume.

First I considered a function tacked onto the end in which I would call, say, `printf "%b" "\u"` in order to cut the current line, plug in another `printf`, paste it back in, and a quote or two at the beginning, then do what little is needed at the end. I don't know how to make this work though, I'm sorry to say. And even if I did, I couldn't hope for any real reliability/portability with this method due to the varying ways shells interpret `escape` sequences, not to mention the terminal emulators they run in. Perhaps `stty` could offer a way forward along these lines, but if so, you won't find it here... now, anyway.

I eventually instead resorted to actually copying the current command's `/proc/{PID}/cmdline` to a variable, then (shamefully) killing it entirely, and finally wrapping it as I pleased. On the plus side, this is very easily done, very quickly done (though I can imagine arguing its 'efficiency' either way), and seems mostly to work, regardless of the original input, whether that be an alias, a variable, a function, etc. I believe it is also POSIX portable (though I can't remember if I need to specify the `kill SIGNALS` by name for POSIX or not), and is definitely no nonsense.

On the other hand, its elegance certainly leaves much to be desired, and, though it's probably not worth worrying about, it does waste entirely a single `PID.` And it doesn't stop *completely* the shell spam; that is, in my shell I have enabled background `jobs` reporting with `set` and so, when first run, the shell kindly informs me that I've just opened and wasted a `PID` in two lines. Also, because I copy the `../cmdline` instead of interfacing directly with the `0` file descriptor, I expect pipes and `;` and etc to be problematic. This I can, and likely will, fix myself very soon.

I will fix that, that is, if I cannot find a way to instead make use of, as I suspect can be done,`SIGTSTP` + `SIGCONT` by first suspending the process outside a subshell then within one continuing it after redirecting the subshell's output. It seems that this works unreliably for reasons I haven't yet discovered, but I think it's promising. Perhaps `nohup` and a `trap` (to effectively `rehup` it, as it were) is what is needed, but I'm not really sure how to put those together either...

Amyway, without further ado, my semi-aborted, backwards gui launcher:

```
% _G() { ( 
    _gui_cmd="$(tr '\0' ' ' </proc/"$\!"/cmdline )" ; 
    kill -9 "$\!" ; 
    exec eval "${_gui_cmd} &" ) 
    &>/dev/null 2&>1 
}
% google-chrome-beta --disk-cache-dir="/tmp/cache" --disk-cache-size=100000000 &_G                                                   
[1] 2674
[1]  + 2674 killed     google-chrome-beta --disk-cache-dir="/tmp/cache" --disk-cache-   
%
```

So another problem one might encounter if attempting to do similar is the order of expansion the shell assumes. Without some trick such as mine you're sure to have some serious difficulty expanding your function before the prior command snags it as an argument. I believe I have guarded against this without unnecessary redundancy by simply tacking my `_G` function call onto the original command's `&` background intstruction. Simply add `&_G`to the tail-end of the command you wish to run and, well, good luck.

-Mike

P.S. Ok, so writing that last sentence makes me think of what might be done with `tee`.